# Why is my post closed?

Tags: discussion

Why is [What is the scope of a public key added by apt-key?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/576982/what-is-the-scope-of-a-public-key-added-by-apt-key) closed? Please clarify the stated reason. (see my comments to the reply below for more information)

Answer (score 5):

I closed your question because it was brought to my attention, by another user, that the question has been cross posted on AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222590/what-is-the-scope-of-a-public-key-added-by-apt-key

Cross-posting is generally not permitted, see [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: Generally speaking (not for this case), if I remember correctly, cross posting is not unacceptable if it is not expected to receive reply. Additionally, if a site has been fair without me having to worry my posts being downoted, closed and removed into invisibility, will I have to resort to cross posting?

Comment: In this case, I remember I wasn't satisfied by the answer in the link you gave (do check out my comment there), so I posted here, trying to get second opinion. Is that not reasonable?

Comment: Things now went a step further in the wrong direction, after my chat account was suspended for two months on all the sites, because some moderator at this site discriminated against me while allowing themselves to talk about the  similar and many other topics. I am still waiting for reinstatement of my chat account.

Comment: @Tim Neither question references the other (explaining the cross-posting) and both are verbatim copies of each other (not tailored for the individual sites). Neither question has accepted answers, which makes me believe you're not happy with the answer on U&L either. Since the U&L question is newer, it makes more sense to close it here than over on the Ubuntu site. You may obviously choose to delete your question over there in which case I'm more than happy to reopen your question here on U&L.

Comment: @Tim I deleted the first comment here. Once again: if you have problems with the moderation of another site, take it to that site. We will not give you a platform to complain about or attack other site moderators.

Comment: ... and I have edited one of @Tim's subsequent comments to remove a similar comment.